# Problems with cloning an object (.clone) in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am cloning a flash in ie and change some variable while that. This is the function:

```
$(function() {
  $("select[name='variation3']").live('change', function() {
    var player = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('object:first');
    if(player.length == 0)
      player = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.player_not_single, .player_singele');

    var $param = player.find("param[name='flashvars']");
    var path = player.closest('.post1').attr('data-demo');

    //$param.attr('value', $param.attr('value').replace(/soundFile=([^&]+)/, 'soundFile=' + path + $(this).find(':selected').val() + '.mp3'));

    $param.attr("value", function(i,v) { return v.replace(/soundFile=([^&]+)/, 'soundFile=' + path + $(this).find(':selected').val() + '.mp3'); });

    var new_player = player.clone();
    new_player.insertBefore(player);
    player.remove();
  });
});
```

In FF it works fine, but inIE it makes problems. This is the code before the cloning:

```
<object name="audioplayer_1" width="270" height="24" id="audioplayer_1"
        classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        style="outline-style:none; outline-color:invert; outline-width:medium;">  
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>  
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>  
  <param name="menu" value="false"/>  
  <param name="flashvars"  value="animation=no&encode=no&initialvolume=60&remaining=no&noinfo=yes&buffer=3&checkpolicy=no&rtl=no&bg=363635&text=333333&leftbg=4f4f4f&lefticon=787171&volslider=71bced&voltrack=777987&rightbg=4d4d4d&rightbghover=66a7d9&righticon=969696&righticonhover=000000&track=c2bebe&loader=5f91f5&border=000000&tracker=90b7d1&skip=b3b3b3&soundFile=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gameaudio.net%2Fprelisten%2Fanotherworld%2Ffulledit.mp3&playerID=audioplayer_1"/>  
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.gameaudio.net/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/assets/player.swf?ver=2.0.4.1"/>  
</object>
```

And this the code after cloning:

```
<object name="audioplayer_1" width="270" height="24" id="audioplayer_1"
        classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        style="outline-style:none; outline-color:invert; outline-width:medium;">  
  <param name="_cx" value="7143"/>  
  <param name="_cy" value="635"/>  
  <param name="FlashVars" value=""/>  
  <param name="Movie" value="http://www.gameaudio.net/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/assets/player.swf?ver=2.0.4.1"/>  
  <param name="WMode" value="Transparent"/>  
  <param name="BGColor" value="FFFFFF"/>  
  [...]  
</object>
```

It is not the same. In parts yes, but not all and esp. the most important parts are missing.
What could be the error?

UPDATE:
This is my current code:
'function embedAudioPlayer(replaceElemIdStr, audioFile) {

```
swfobject.embedSWF(   
    "http://www.gameaudio.net/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/assets  /player.swf?ver=2.0.4.1",   
    replaceElemIdStr,   
    width,   
    height,   
    "9.0.115",   
    "expressInstall.swf",  
    {  
        soundFile: audioFile  
    });
```

}

$(function() {

$("select[name='variation3']").live('change', function() {

```
player = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.player_not_single,   .player_singele');

var $param = player.find("param[name='flashvars']");  
var path = player.closest('.post1').attr('data-demo');  
var audioFile = path + $(this).find(':selected').val() + '.mp3';  
var uniqueId = 'audio-' + +new Date;  
player.replaceWith('<div id="+uniqueId+"/>');  
embedAudioPlayer(uniqueId, audioFile);
```

}); 
    '

function embedAudioPlayer(replaceElemIdStr, audioFile) {
var swfobject = audioplayer_swfobject;
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "http://www.gameaudio.net/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/assets/player.swf?ver=2.0.4.1", 
        replaceElemIdStr, 
        250, 
        50, 
        "9.0.115", 
        "expressInstall.swf",
        {
            soundFile: audioFile
        });
}

$(function() {

$("select[name='variation3']").live('change', function() {

```
player = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.player_not_single, .player_singele');

var $param = player.find("param[name='flashvars']");
var path = player.closest('.post1').attr('data-demo');
var audioFile = path + $(this).find(':selected').val() + '.mp3';
var uniqueId = 'audio-' + +new Date;
player.replaceWith('<div id="+uniqueId+"/>');
embedAudioPlayer(uniqueId, audioFile);
```

});

Update:

`
  function embedAudioPlayer(replaceElemIdStr, audioFile) {
var swfobject = audioplayer_swfobject;
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "http://www.gameaudio.net/wp-content/plugins/audio-player/assets/player.swf?ver=2.0.4.1", 
        replaceElemIdStr, 
        250, 
        50, 
        "9.0.115", 
        "expressInstall.swf",
        {
            soundFile: audioFile
        });
}

$(function() {

$("select[name='variation3']").live('change', function() {

```
player = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.player_not_single, .player_singele');

var $param = player.find("param[name='flashvars']");
var path = player.closest('.post1').attr('data-demo');
var audioFile = path + $(this).find(':selected').val() + '.mp3';
var uniqueId = 'audio-' + +new Date;
player.replaceWith('<div id="+uniqueId+"/>');
embedAudioPlayer(uniqueId, audioFile);
```

});`

Comment: Would you post a URL to an example page with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and everything but IE uses the [Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface (NPAPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) for Flash.  Firefox (et al.) use the `param` elements but IE reads from the attributes.  It's annoying specifying everything twice but [that's what you have to do](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) unless you're using something like [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) that does it for you (highly recommended) .

Updated based on using swfobject:

Sounds like you're essentially trying to reimplement `swfobject.embedSWF` Using `jQuery.clone`.  I'm sure it could be made to work but I suggest you stick to swfobject for Flash embedding and jQuery for the DOM.  I'd use the following structure:

```
function embedAudioPlayer(replaceElemIdStr, audioFile) {
    // customize these options for the audio player you're using
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "yourplayer.swf", 
        replaceElemIdStr, 
        width, 
        height, 
        "9.0.115", 
        "expressInstall.swf",
        {
            soundFile = audioFile
        });
}

$("select[name='variation3']").live('change', function() {
    // ...
    var audioFile = path + $(this).find(':selected').val() + '.mp3';
    var uniqueId = 'audio-' + +new Date;
    player.replaceWith('<div id="+uniqueId+"/>');
    embedAudioPlayer(uniqueId, audioFile);
});
```

1. Create a `embedAudioPlayer` function and use it for everything both at initial page load and in response to page events.
2. When responding to page events use jQuery to determine the soundFile url and the destination element where a new audio player should be created.

Comment: swf object is used. It generates the 1st code above. It seems that the swf object is not executed, after the flash is cloned. Can I call it at the end of my function?

Comment: Added suggested structure since you are using swfobject

Comment: Please have alook in my edit above. This is what I have now. I am getting an error: swf object is undefined...:(

Comment: Is swfobject.js included before your the script where `embedAudioPlayer` is defined?

Comment: It should be included as `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>` in the HTML before the script tag that includes your other js.  You don't have to use the the version of swfobject hosted by ajax.googleapis.com but it's generally a good idea.

Comment: ahhh. Yes and no. I am using a wp plugin for the player. The swfobject cam with this plugin. I think it is a kind of swfobject, but begins with theses lines: `var audioplayer_swfobject=function(){var d="undefined",R="object",s="Shockwav`.. this file is included, yes.

Comment: Looks the audio player is bringing in its own copy of swfobject.  You could add `var swfobject = audioplayer_swfobject;` which would make swfobject available using its standard name.

Comment: Okay. Please have a alook at my last update. The player is not getting replaced. What could be the error?